# Defining a command with options

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have two problems. First I don't know why but **Texmaker** doesn't compile when I define this command:

```
\newcommand{\Axes}{\draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](-5,0)--(5,0)\node[below]{$x$};
\foreach \x in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[xshift=\x cm](0pt,-2pt)--(0pt,2pt);
\draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](0,-5)--(0,5)node[left]{$y$};
\foreach \y in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[yshift=\y cm](-2p,0pt)--(2pt,0pt);}
```

What's the problem with this? How to solve this problem?
And my second question, how can I define this command with options? I want my `\Axes` command to look like this:
`\Axes[(x axis length),(y axis length)]` Please help me, I rarely define commands and I don't have experience about it. Thank you.

***The full code***

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\Axes}{\draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](-5,0)--(5,0)\node[below]{$x$};
\foreach \x in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[xshift=\x cm](0pt,-2pt)--(0pt,2pt);
\draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](0,-5)--(0,5)node[left]{$y$};
\foreach \y in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[yshift=\y cm](-2p,0pt)--(2pt,0pt);}

\begin{document}
\tikz{\Axes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `-2p` should be `-2pt`, most likely

Comment: Oh yes, I just wrote quickly.

Comment: The `\Axes[...]` is unclear. Should it be an optional argument?

Comment: Yes. You can set the length of axes. It is optional, like in the command <code> \draw[thick](0,0)--(1,0);</code>.

Comment: I've deleted the `texmaker` tag, since this is not related to the editor itself.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer, very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-2p` should be `-2pt` and there is `;` missing after the first `\draw` statement, in my point of view.

**Update**: I've added a new `\AxesNew` version with an optional argument and a splitter helper command. Caveat: You have to enclose the lengths in a `{...}` pair yet!

A better approach would use `expl3` and its splitting features (i.e. `\seq_set_split:Nnn` but that's perhaps too much ado ;-))

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\Axes}{%
  \draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](-5,0)--(5,0);\node[below]{$x$};
  \foreach \x in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} 
    \draw[xshift=\x cm](0pt,-2pt)--(0pt,2pt);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=5mm,width=2mm]}](0,-5)--(0,5)node[left]{$y$};
    \foreach \y in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} 
      \draw[yshift=\y cm](-2pt,0pt)--(2pt,0pt);
}

    \def\ostalslittlehelper#1,#2{%
\def\ostalfirstarg{#1}%
\def\ostalsecondarg{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\AxesNew}[1][{5mm},{2mm}]{%
  \ostalslittlehelper#1%
    \draw[-{Latex[length=\ostalfirstarg,width=\ostalsecondarg]}](-5,0)--(5,0);\node[below]{$x$};
  \foreach \x in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} 
    \draw[xshift=\x cm](0pt,-2pt)--(0pt,2pt);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=\ostalfirstarg,width=\ostalsecondarg]}](0,-5)--(0,5)node[left]{$y$};
    \foreach \y in{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} 
      \draw[yshift=\y cm](-2pt,0pt)--(2pt,0pt);
}

\begin{document}
\tikz{\AxesNew}

\tikz{\AxesNew[{8mm},{10mm}]}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You've answered this question magnificently!

Comment: @ostal123: Alright, glad I could help. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Anyway I don't understand what these commands mean:

    \def\ostalslittlehelper#1,#2{%
    \def\ostalfirstarg{#1}%
    \def\ostalsecondarg{#2}%
    }

Comment: Can you explain me how these commands work and what do they mean? Or where can I find a document about them?

Comment: The argument is -- by your request -- **length**,**width**, so I have to split this into two separate lengths. `\ostalslittlehelper#1,#2` does actually delimit the arguments by this `,` and stores the argument to two separate macros which are used then in the `length=...` etc. specifications of TikZ

Comment: And where did you learn this? I mean I've never seen these commands in any LaTeX manuals.

Comment: @ostal123: I've learned from the best TeX Gurus here ;-) Actually, `\def...#1,#2` is plain TeX usage -- it's not used normally (and shown) in LaTeX manuals, but a handy trick!

Comment: By the way: Two years ago I had less reputation than you have right now -- and look on my progress! I learned so much here -- I was a skilled LaTeX user for standard things, but I was no programmer then.

Comment: Okay, and may I ask you to teach me some handy tricks? You are the best LaTeX user I've met on this page. Can I send questions to your e-mail if there's a problem which I can't handle? A problem like this question.

Comment: @ostal123: I am 'good', but definitely not the best one. I can't answer questions on LuaTeX or Tikz actually. You may send me mail of course -- see my profile page, my mail address is stored there.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me send questions. Actually I don't use LuaTex.